# MVVM LightToolkit and WPF Datagrid AutoGeneratingColumn event

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

Is it possible to use MVVMLight Toolkits EventToCommand approach for handling Datagrid's AutoGeneratingColumn event? I tried the following approach, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="AutoGeneratingColumn">
                    <mvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding TestCommand}">  </mvvm:EventToCommand>
                </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.

I'd recommend setting your Xaml and Command Signature as I've outlined below.

**XAML**

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="AutoGeneratingColumn">
        <mvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding TestCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

**C# - In your DataContext (ViewModel)**

```
public void Test(AutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    // handle however you need to here
}
```